# pyglet Segmentation faults and other errors

Tags: python, linux, opengl, archlinux, pyglet

I'm attempting to load images for sprites using the Python library [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/). The original purpose was game-related, but I believe I have distilled the issue down to a single line of code. In the Python shell, I import pyglet, and then I run this line of code (or something equivalent):

```
pyglet.image.load("image.png")
```

Python quits, and the terminal outputs:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Sometimes it doesn't do this, though, and instead throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/__init__.py", line 351, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._module, name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/__init__.py", line 357, in __getattr__
    __import__(import_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 236, in <module>
    import pyglet.window
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1816, in <module>
    gl._create_shadow_window()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 205, in _create_shadow_window
    _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 515, in __init__
    context = config.create_context(gl.current_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py", line 186, in create_context
    return XlibContextARB(self, share)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py", line 300, in __init__
    super(XlibContext13, self).__init__(config, share)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py", line 203, in __init__
    raise gl.ContextException('Could not create GL context') 
pyglet.gl.ContextException: Could not create GL context
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/__init__.py", line 351, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._module, name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/__init__.py", line 357, in __getattr__
    __import__(import_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl import gl_info
ImportError: cannot import name 'gl_info'
```

(I'm not sure why it alternates between these two.)

In addition,

```
pyglet.window.Window()
```

also throws the exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 515, in __init__
    context = config.create_context(gl.current_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py", line 186, in create_context
    return XlibContextARB(self, share)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py", line 300, in __init__
    super(XlibContext13, self).__init__(config, share)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py", line 203, in __init__
    raise gl.ContextException('Could not create GL context') 
pyglet.gl.ContextException: Could not create GL context
```

when run from the shell. Sometimes it runs when run from a file (it'll run, fail on subsequent runs, and then eventually work for another run), and if I remember correctly it runs without issue from a Python program frozen with cx_Freeze.

I haven't managed to find anything newer than a couple years old on Google. I don't know much about OpenGL; at present I use pyglet because of how it simplifies building apps.

I'm running 64-bit Manjaro Linux with XFCE, an AMD CPU, and an AMD integrated graphics card (with the closed Catalyst drivers). I have Python 3.4.2 and pyglet 1.2.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

*Now (2016.10.30) this issue is fixet. On the website development present report about it.*

Pyglet website developers is an example of image loader: http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/image_viewer.html.

In the my Archlinux system *(Linux alw 3.19.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Mar 7 20:59:30 CET 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux)* this error persist - core dumped with the python-3, bat work fine with the python-2. I am used newest version of the pyglet - 1.2.2.

On MS-Win 8.1 this example works without any errors. I think the problem is in the wrong job this module.

I am reported about this bug on the development site https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/issue/25/core-dumped-on-linux-64

Now you can use only PNG format:

```
...
from pyglet.image.codecs.png import PNGImageDecoder

fname = 'pennant.png'
img_pennant = pyglet.image.load(fname, decoder=PNGImageDecoder())
...
```

This code not core dumped.